# Close Any Dialog/MessageBox From C# applications

Tags: c#-4.0

We are working on .NET environment.
Mainly my applications having operation on microsoft files(open/close/save)

As there are many message box prompt comes while opening few microsoft files.
So user has to close this dialog manually and then it will start processing next file.

So is there any way, we can perform our process without any message box interruption ?
Or is there a way, we can close any dialog/messagebox from C# code ?

Thanks

Comment: `So is there any way, we can perform our process without any message box interruption ?` Probably, if you tell us what you're doing.

Comment: We are performing operation like, identification of Track changes in MsWord file, it update database related to track changes fields identification..now we are processing this operation for large no of files in different machines & so we can not ask user to keep eye on running operations...so for the MessageBox which display while opening any problematic files , we wanted to skip or press any button like Yes/No or any which helps to keep process running..

Comment: Consider using a third-party Word library.  Automating Office is a recipe for worlds of pain.